# How should i include a component from the vaadin directory with gradle?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Found no information on how i should include vaadin directory components correctly in my gradle bulid.

just doing

```
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:$vaadinVersion")

    // Vaadin
    implementation("com.vaadin:vaadin-core")
    implementation("com.vaadin.componentfactory:selection-grid-flow")
    providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"
    ...
```

.... does not work

searched the internet and the vaadin page
there a demo snippets for maven around ... those work perfectly.

Comment: You need to add the version (like you did with javax.servlet). Other than that: "does not work" does not help one bit! Add the error/stacktrace you get.

Comment: Cheers! Your comment just helped me out. First, add the version with :x.x.x. Second, and more important, add the /vaadin-addons repo, where most stuff from the vaadin directory ist hosted, e.g. `maven { url "https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons" }`

Answer (score 1):

Complete Solution is:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { setUrl("https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases") }
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url "https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons" }
}

.........

dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:$vaadinVersion")

    // Vaadin
    implementation("com.vaadin:vaadin-core")
    implementation("com.vaadin.componentfactory:selection-grid-flow:2.0.0")
    providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"
.....
```

.. in case one want's to include the selection-grid component from the vaadin directory.